# Adding Sidebar in Chrome Devtools - Network Pane

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to develop a extension for Chrome Devtools - Network. Is it possible to add sidepane to network tab? I tried to add to Elements pane (just to test) as below:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane("Options",
    function(sidebar) {
        sidebar.setPage("Sidebar.html");
        sidebar.setHeight("8ex");
});
```

and it worked, however the code below won't work:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.network.createSidebarPane("Options",
    function(sidebar) {
        sidebar.setPage("Sidebar.html");
        sidebar.setHeight("8ex");
});
```

What am i doing wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation lists](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#property-elements) only two built-in panels that may have sidebars: `Elements` and `Sources`.
The layout of `Network` panel doesn't have any sidebars by design that's why it doesn't work.